# Put a component in a table column header?

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm want to put a component e.g. a button as a table column header in vaadin.

Is there anyway to do this?

I had thought I could do:

```
Button button = new Button();
matrixTable.setVisibleColumns(new Object[] { button });
```

However the column header is just the package name of the button & not the button itself.

N.b. I am aware of Table Header Clicklisteners this is not what I am after.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does a vaadin addon for this exist??

Comment: It would involve quite a bit of work (including client side) to get a real button inside a table header. But your suggestion (a clicklistener on a header) would be a cheap "button". Alternatively, you could perhaps simply hide the header and put the buttons in the first data row?

Comment: Theres an idea, would I have to deal with the header sorting myself though?

Comment: You could add sorting to the real-button-in-data-row's click handler. But then you'd need a button in each column, maybe that's not what you want. Anyway, could you explain why you don't want your own suggestion of clicklistener-on-header?

Comment: It is possible using CSS to get headers look and behave like normal buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible at the moment in Vaadin. It is already reported in **[Vaadin trac](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/8432)** and awaits implementation. However you can use various techniques to get desired effect including:

1. [Write your own custom component](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.eclipse.html#gwt.eclipse.widget) (maybe based on com.vaadin.ui.Table)
2. Use CSS to style column header so it will looks and behave (on hover) like button
3. [Use Javascript to inject html components](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/774477/8020605) (checkbox, button) and style them with CSS